# IE8 opacity error

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get transparency in a background of a `<li>` element. the opacity is being a problem in IE8. 
instead of the background, the whole `<li>` is getting transparent.

```
#weeklyPrizeBlocksWrapper li {
    font:bold 11px Arial;
    color: #535353;
    height: 67px;
    background-color: #e4c39b;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
    opacity:0.5; 
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 6px;
    float: left;
    dislpay: block;
    margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: that will be the case of all browsers. if you want only the background to be transparent, look into css3 opacity

Comment: css3 wont work in IE7/8. any other solution?

Comment: Yes the other solution is to use a transparent image as background. see more details in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opacity is applied to all the elements in the list items.

if you want to apply the opacity to the background, it is available in CSS3:

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
```

the `a` is for alpha

For wider support on all browsers, the common to do it is to use a transparent png image.
you can use photoshop or any image editor software to decrease the opacity to the level you need.

Comment: IE7/8 wont support CSS3. any other alternative?

Comment: @amit, the other solution is to use a transparent gif or png, see my update above

Answer (score 0):

Google for transparent background in IE. IE has a filter for that. opacity and relative filter are always applied to the whole element, in all browsers.